# Windows phone 8 AdMob ReceiveAd not working

Tags: windows-phone-8, admob

I have made unity application, and I have exported it to visual studio so I can add Google AdMob. I just want to show interstitial ad when ad loads. I am using latest Google.dll file ver:6.5.13.0. Here is my code:

```
        //Google AdMob begin
        private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
        AdRequest adRequest;
        Boolean interstitialApploaded = false;
        int test = 0;
        //Google AdMob end

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            var bridge = new UnityBridge();
            UnityApp.SetBridge(bridge);
            InitializeComponent();
            bridge.Control = DrawingSurfaceBackground;

            interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd("my interstitial ID");
            interstitialAd.ReceivedAd += OnAdReceived;
            interstitialAd.FailedToReceiveAd += OnFailedToReceiveAd;
            interstitialAd.DismissingOverlay += OnDismissingOverlay;

            adRequest = new AdRequest();
            adRequest.ForceTesting = true;
            interstitialAd.LoadAd(adRequest);
        }

        //Google AdMob BEGIN
        private void OnDismissingOverlay(object sender, AdEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Ad dismissed.");
            interstitialAd.LoadAd(adRequest);
        }

        private void OnFailedToReceiveAd(object sender, AdErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Ad failed to load!!!!");
            interstitialApploaded = false;
            test = 1;
        }

        private void OnAdReceived(object sender, AdEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Ad loaded. Have fun!");
            interstitialApploaded = true;
            test = 2;
            interstitialAd.ShowAd();
        }
```

Now, the problem is that I am not getting any of the `Debug.Writeline` messages. So I guess `ReceiveAd` is not working.
Any thoughts?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be Right, check your **internet connection** and **Capabilities** that are needed for Ad-loading and try after removing `adRequest.ForceTesting = true;` that is for test Ad Interstitial.

Comment: I have internet connection. What capabilities?

Comment: Refer this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-manifest-capabilities(v=msads.20).aspx and this for how to modify app manifest file http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj247542(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: All **Capabilities** are ok. I removed `adRequest.ForceTesting = true;` and it is "working" now. Sometimes when I build it, ads are there, and sometimes they won't load. I don't get any `Debug.Writeline()` that I have set.

Comment: check adrequest is calling or not all time by putting DebugPoint. mark as answered if answer helped you

Comment: When I go step by step through debuger, it all works fine. My only guess is that first time when I call `interstitialAd.LoadAd(adRequest);`, it doesn't load.

Comment: remove interstitialAd.LoadAd(adRequest); from OnDismissingOverlay and try

Comment: I don't think it is in the code. From 10 buildings, 5 times ads were working. And I need loading in `OnDismissingOverlay` because when I dismiss ad, it should load again.

Comment: I have same problem. Ads arent loading sometimes. Have You solved it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the advertise through Unity with its advertisers there will be always an exception if you try to change the exported .sln file from Unity

Comment: I am not calling add from Unity. I am calling it from VisualStudio because I want it to load as soon as application starts. See comments above.